# How to make Listview/ScrollView to respond to scroll event after wrapping within TouchableWithoutFeedback

Tags: listview, react-native, scrollview

Use case - I have a element that responds to onPress, this element have multiple children and one of them is Listview/Scrollview, like shown below

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress ={this.presshandler.bind(this}>
    <View style ={{flex:1}}>
       <Children1>
       <Children2>
       <Children3>
       <ListView dataSource ={someDataSource}
          horizontal={true}
          renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)} />
    </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

so component in this format is clickable everywhere and thats what the desired behaviour, but when I tried to scroll listview it also fire onPress of TouchableWithoutFeedback. If I put scrollview/listview as the direct child of TouchableWithoutFeedback than scrolling can be done but in that case onPress of TouchableWithoutFeedback is not firing, I mean like below

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress ={this.presshandler.bind(this}>
  <ListView dataSource ={someDataSource}
    horizontal={true}
    renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)} />
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

In 2nd case listview is scrollview but when I tried to click listview (i.e. a child of TouchableWithoutFeedback) that onPress is not firing, can someone please suggest me a feasible solution on workaround. Thanks

Comment: Touchable* components will hijack the touches on child components. In order to help, it would be useful to understand what it is that you're trying to achieve? Having a tappable/scrollable UI component seems like a non-standard UX pattern.

Comment: A more typical pattern would be to wrap each child of the ScrollView (or each row of the ListView) in a Touchable, and then trigger any touch action on that component.

Comment: @jevakallio I have a list of cards having lots of details, every card is clickable, now every card have some user (lets say who liked the app), so list of these user is horizontally scrollable, I can scrolling properly if listview is the only child of TouchableWithoutFeedback

Comment: Then make the ScrollView/ListView child components clickable with `TouchableWithoutFeedback`? It doesn't really make sense that the ScrollView's *parent* should be tappable, as well as the children?

Comment: I don't want to make children of inner scrollview tappable, they should just be scrollable, I just want to make whole scrollview tappable (just like it is integral part of card)

Comment: Ok, then. Good luck!

Comment: I am a bit lost on what are you trying to achieve. You still need help respond with a @call

Comment: @Eduard even I am confused about the need of our designer,